# Difference between In Memory OLTP v.s. Temp table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, in-memory-database

SQL Server 2014 has a new feature called In Memory OLTP and it could store tables in memory. Temp table could do the similar thing by caching the temp table in memory. So, is there any difference? and How about the performance of these two ways?

Answer (score 0):

There is so much difference between in memory OLTP and the contents of a temp table being stored in memory, that no succinct answer would really do it justice. They're apples and oranges. Additionally, the benefits of in-memory OLTP versus any other solution is going to be largely dependant upon the specific problem you're trying to solve. If you're interested in the feature,  I would recommend reading the white papers which can be linked to from this blog post:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/04/27/sqlauthority-news-two-microsoft-whitepaper-on-in-memory-oltp/