# Using In-Memory OLTP Tables instead of temporary tables

Tags: sql-server-2014, temp-tables, in-memory, in-memory-oltp

`SQL Server 2014` introduced what it seems to be a great feature: [In-Memory OLTP (In-Memory Optimization)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133186(v=sql.120).aspx). It reminds me of `MySQL's` [MEMORY Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-storage-engine.html), which I have tried several years ago and obtained greater performance.

I know it has been [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957345/difference-between-in-memory-oltp-v-s-temp-table) asked, but I am interested in a more targeted scenario:

Several `SSRS` reports use large stored procedures that, for performance reasons (really ugly and slow execution plans for queries with lots of joins, grouping etc.), split the logic by using temporary tables to hold partial results.

Since temporary table are written to the disk, I expect to have a performance impact when dealing with large quantity of data (tens or even hundred of thousand of lines).

Does using `In-Memory OLTP tables` make sense in this scenario? I am thinking about the following pros and cons.

**Pros:**

- should be significantly faster, since all data is stored in memory

**Cons:**

- requires explicit sessions separation (table should include some sort of session identifier to not mix data from various `SPID`s)
- requires explicit data cleanup to avoid memory starvation (as opposed to temporary tables automatically being dropped after exiting declaration scope)
- requires to pay attention to the data volume stored in the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got that right.

Note, though, that temp tables like any other table are written lazily (even more lazily than normal). The writing to disk is usually not on the critical path because it happens asynchronously. Except for very big temp tables that exhaust SQL Servers ability to keep dirty buffers in memory.

Also, if the temp table is deallocated quickly there will not be any page writes at all.

So the "pro" that you have listed there often does not come into (full) effect.

That said in-memory tables tend to use less CPU even in interop mode. So the "pro" is always at least a little bit true.

You can consider using schema-only Hekaton tables. That will not cause any data writes for sure.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. In the cases I have seen, temp tables can reach 100K large records (20-30 columns) and the procedure may run for as long as 10 minutes. Once I have some free time, I will give a try on a SQL Server 2014 instance (currently the application is running on a SQL Server 2012).

Comment: If the procedure ran for that time it certainly was not due to that temp table. Sounds like 10MB or so. Should be populated incl. IO in 1sec or so.